# Problem with mouseenter for a clip-path animation (CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, css

I have updated my post because I've come up with some solutions since last week.

---

I'm having a problem with a clip-path section.

I would like my clip-path (circle) to shrink and then disappear when the mouse is leaving the clip section, and to expand again when it's entering the clip section.

The shrinking is working but not the expanding (see code below).

All help is very welcome!

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

```js
const circleClip = document.querySelector('#hidden');
let divSize = document.querySelector('#top').offsetHeight;

function removeIntro() {
  circleClip.classList.remove('intro');
}

function circleMove(e) {
  removeIntro();
  circleClip.style.setProperty('--x', e.clientX + 'px');
  circleClip.style.setProperty('--y', e.clientY - divSize + 'px');
}

circleClip.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
  circleClip.classList.toggle('shrink');
});

/*This one doesn't work on desktop*/
circleClip.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  circleClip.classList.toggle('appear');
});

circleClip.addEventListener('mousemove', circleMove);
circleClip.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  removeIntro();
  
  let touch = e.touches[0];
  e.preventDefault();
  
  circleClip.style.setProperty('--x', touch.clientX + 'px');
  circleClip.style.setProperty('--y', touch.clientY - divSize + 'px');
});

/*This one doesn't work on mobile*/
  circleClip.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
  circleClip.classList.toggle('appear');
});

  circleClip.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
  circleClip.classList.toggle('shrink');
});
```

```css
body {
     position: relative;
     margin: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#hidden p {
  padding: 10%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#hidden {
  font-size: 7vh !important;
  line-height: 1em;
  background: red;
    min-height: 100vh;
    clip-path: circle(10% at var(--x) var(--y));
  cursor: none;
}
 #hidden.intro {
     clip-path: circle(0% at 50% 50%);
     animation: circleIntro 1800ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) both;
}

@keyframes circleIntro {
     100% {
         clip-path: circle(10% at 50% 50%);
    }
}

.shrink {
  clip-path: circle(10% at 50% 50%);
  animation: shrink 800ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) both;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  100% {
    clip-path: circle(0% at 50% 50%);
  }
}

.appear {
  clip-path: circle(0% at 50% 50%);
  animation: appear 800ms cubic-bezier(0645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) both;
}

@keyframes appear {
  100% {
    clip-path: circle(10% at 50% 50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="top"><h1>This is another div</h1></div>
<div id="hidden" class="intro">
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "goes out of the text area", which area are you referring to? Also, for touch-based device compatibility you might want to also listen to the `touchmove` event.

Comment: I mean that the web page will have several div and the clip section should be active only when the cursor is on the .main text or on the .clip_container div. When the cursor is out of this container, the clip should shrink until it disappears. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're looking for something like this?

You can separate the event handlers into their own functions:

```
function showCircle(e) {
    $(".clip").css({
        "-webkit-clip-path": "circle(0px at var(--x, 0) var(--y, 0))"
    });
}

function hideCircle(e) {
    $(".clip").css({
        "-webkit-clip-path": "circle(0px at var(--x, 0) var(--y, 0))"
    });
}

function moveCircle(e) {
    $(".clip").css ({
        '--x': e.pageX,
        '--y': e.pageY - $("#previoussection").height() - $("#clip_section").height()
    });
}
```

Then register the handlers for mouse interaction,

```
$(document).mousemove(moveCircle);
$(".clip_container").mouseleave(hideCircle);
$(".clip_container").mouseenter(showCircle);
```

and for touch interaction.

```
$(document).touchmove(moveCircle);
$(".clip_container").touchstart(hideCircle);
$(".clip_container").touchend(showCircle);
```

The circle isn't shrinking away because its CSS is never changed back to the 0 radius circle.

I think the key here is making sure you change the "clip-path" CSS property to the full value representing the circle you want to see whenever a relevant event fires.

It's also worth noting that your `mouseStopped` function never gets called in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation. It helps, but it doesn't work with mouseenter and I don't understand why. I would like the circle to shrink when leaving the text and to grow when entering it. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough.
I have added your code and this one to my current jquery code.
$(".clip p").mouseenter(function(e) {
       $(".clip").css({
            "-webkit-clip-path": "circle(2.5em at var(--x, 0) var(--y, 0))"
        });
 }); 
Is that what you were explaining or am I missing something?

Comment: For the mouseenter event, did you set the appropriate radius? instead of 0px, it should be 2.5em.

So the whole CSS rule, passed as an object into the jQuery CSS function, would be like `{"-webkit-clip-path": "circle(2.5em at var(--x, 0) var(--y, 0))"}`

Comment: Yes, I set the radius to 2.5em

Comment: That's my fault, I used the wrong element to bind the event. I'm updating the answer with the full JS I have.

Comment: Now it's working fine! Thank you very much. The "mousestopped" function was indeed used in a previous version. I deleted it. 
I'll test the full code on the mobile later or tomorrow before I close this post, but you answered my first question, thank you very much!

Comment: I have updated my JQuery/CSS and it works fine (without "-webkit-" for Firefox though).
Unfortunately, I don't find a good solution for touch screens (I'm a beginner in touchmove events). I'm still reading some documentation, if you have any advice or tips in the meantime, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Definitely use the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events) for reference on things like this. I added some code to the answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you for the MDN, it will definitely be helpful! 

I have tried your code and here's what I have: 

If I replace my current code with yours, the circle follows the mouse cursor with high latency (on desktop). On mobile, the circle does not follow the movement of the finger (like drag-and-drop). 

If I leave both codes, the circle follows the cursor again without latency on desktop, but I have the same problem on mobile. 

For the showCircle function, the clip-path radius must be set at 2em and not 0px, right?

I'm going to do a few more tests.

Comment: I have edited my question and my snippet because I found a solution with Javascript. It works partially on mobile (dragging the circle on the clip section is now ok). However, there are still some issues that I explain in my post. Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance and have a nice weekend!